# Is it possible to test for significance using seaborn barplots in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, statistics-bootstrap, significance

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that looks like this:

```
              Group  Replicate  Time    Normed
0        5ng/mLTGFb          1     1  0.924876
1        5ng/mLTGFb          1     2  0.891171
2        5ng/mLTGFb          1     3  0.928782
3        5ng/mLTGFb          1     4  0.842967
4        5ng/mLTGFb          2     1  0.908404
5        5ng/mLTGFb          2     2  0.886511
6        5ng/mLTGFb          2     3  0.911488
7        5ng/mLTGFb          2     4  0.875320
8        5ng/mLTGFb          3     1  0.921771
9        5ng/mLTGFb          3     2  0.887204
10       5ng/mLTGFb          3     3  0.828524
11       5ng/mLTGFb          3     4  0.873509
12        Glyco0.8%          1     1  0.883661
13        Glyco0.8%          1     2  0.823874
14        Glyco0.8%          1     3  0.875522
15        Glyco0.8%          1     4  0.859953
16        Glyco0.8%          2     1  0.880971
17        Glyco0.8%          2     2  0.832171
18        Glyco0.8%          2     3  0.885903
19        Glyco0.8%          2     4  0.859308
20        Glyco0.8%          3     1  0.894803
21        Glyco0.8%          3     2  0.856890
22        Glyco0.8%          3     3  0.862479
23        Glyco0.8%          3     4  0.846343
24        Glyco2.4%          1     1  0.883367
25        Glyco2.4%          1     2  0.859378
26        Glyco2.4%          1     3  0.893720
27        Glyco2.4%          1     4  0.852863
28        Glyco2.4%          2     1  0.871003
29        Glyco2.4%          2     2  0.840247
30        Glyco2.4%          2     3  0.880209
31        Glyco2.4%          2     4  0.849866
32        Glyco2.4%          3     1  0.906474
33        Glyco2.4%          3     2  0.893899
34        Glyco2.4%          3     3  0.861791
35        Glyco2.4%          3     4  0.841760
36        Glyco4.8%          1     1  0.909556
37        Glyco4.8%          1     2  0.867863
38        Glyco4.8%          1     3  0.875383
39        Glyco4.8%          1     4  0.849258
40        Glyco4.8%          2     1  0.912481
41        Glyco4.8%          2     2  0.862332
42        Glyco4.8%          2     3  0.898971
43        Glyco4.8%          2     4  0.851969
44        Glyco4.8%          3     1  0.920611
45        Glyco4.8%          3     2  0.858697
46        Glyco4.8%          3     3  0.877669
47        Glyco4.8%          3     4  0.842820
48  NegativeControl          1     1  0.896742
49  NegativeControl          1     2  0.828705
50  NegativeControl          1     3  0.898466
51  NegativeControl          1     4  0.840793
52  NegativeControl          2     1  0.889273
53  NegativeControl          2     2  0.830354
54  NegativeControl          2     3  0.838096
55  NegativeControl          2     4  0.843467
56  NegativeControl          3     1  0.859525
57  NegativeControl          3     2  0.823689
58  NegativeControl          3     3  0.833555
59  NegativeControl          3     4  0.840500
```

This data can be plotted quite nicely with `seaborn` and `matplotlib` (assuming the above data was assigned to a variable called `normed`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='Time',y='Normed',data=normed,hue='Group')
plt.legend(loc=(1,0.3))
```

Here is the output:

[image]

However, what I really want to do is perform a t-test to test for statistical significance between groups (ideally one for all n choose 2 combinations of variable but for now lets just say between the negative control at the first and second time point). Does anybody know if `seaborn` supports this or know of another way of performing t-tests on this data? Additionally I've seen that `seaborn` supports bootstrapping statistics, it would be great if I could get confidence intervals for the t-tests as well though this is peripheral really.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Seaborn is a visualization tool. I think you should rather look into statsmodels or other statistics tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [statannot](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot) library. Its very nice. Just do

```
pip install statannot
```

[Here's](https://github.com/webermarcolivier/statannot/blob/master/example/example.ipynb) a ton of examples you can adapt to your needs